# Tikz this surface picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Can someone help me how to draw an image like this in Tikzpicture? I've been looking for an editable image like this on internet but there is not. I actually need to be able to edit the labels on this picture and to configure them, but I'm out of mind how to build a surface and these tangent planes and vectors in a 3d Tikz image.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please don't post questions where you're asking people to do your work for you. Post your code to show what you tried and ask for specific advice on this code.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to do it for me. I just have no experience in drawning 3d images and plots like this, so I'm looking for and advice how to develop at least the surfaces.

Comment: First do you have the equation of the plane...

Comment: Is it about illustrating the exponential map on a surface?

Comment: For the moment, the best advice is trying to reproduce examples from [tikz-3dplot](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf). Draw planes and vectors/coordinators systems. Once you draw the first one, learn how to duplicate them. Lastly, learn (in a total separated file) how to draw a surface. Not easy, but it will be very satisfaying.

Comment: About 3d surfaces, check [this tutorial](https://latexdraw.com/three-dimensional-plotting-in-latex/) and also [4.6.5 Mesh Plots of pgfplots manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

Answer (score 3):

As a start point, I did a quick surface with `mesh` for `z = f(x,y) =x^2 - y^2` and I added a surface with `surf` to draw the plane `y`. The vectors are inside a `scope` in order to format them all together. You may check which function better represent the surface you are looking for. I'd suggest to use [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to find a suitable function faster.

Please, notice the equations are not precise, just a proof of concept. It means, the plane **is not** the tangencial plane at `(0,0)` and vectors **are not** normalized, but `e_3` *is* orthogonal to the plane while `e_1` and `e_2` *are* in the plane.

The second plane is commented, but it represents the second, third, ..., n-th plane you might add.

For illustrative purposes, I create an animation. Tha animation serves only to present the answer here without showing a lot of figure of all possible angles, therefore animation lines are commented. Please, **do not** use animations while learning how to draw, it is time consuming and a simple change numbers in the parameter `view` are more than enough to check the development of your sketch.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
%\begin{animateinline}[poster=first, controls,loop]{10}
%  \multiframe{360}{ii=0+10}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    view={30}{30},
    % view={\ii}{30},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    zlabel=$z$,
    grid]

    \addplot3 [
    domain=-2:2,
    domain y = -2:2,
    samples = 20,
    samples y = 8,
    mesh] {x^2 - y^2};

    \addplot3 [domain=-1:1,
    domain y = -1:1,
    samples = 5,
    surf] {y};

    % \addplot3 [domain=-2:-1,
    %   domain y = -1:1,
    %   samples = 5,
    %   surf,red] {2*(x-y)+3};

    \begin{scope}[-latex,blue,very thick]
      \addplot3 [] coordinates {(0,0,0) (1,0,0)} node[right]{$e_1$};
      \addplot3 [] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,1,1)} node[right]{$e_2$};
      \addplot3 [] coordinates {(0,0,0) (0,-1,1)} node[above]{$e_3$};
    \end{scope}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%  }
%\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's gonna help strongly!

Comment: By the way. Check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645367/140133). It might also be of your interest.